# Make the web browser scroll to the top?

Tags: javascript, scroll

What is the JavaScript to scroll to the top when a button/link/etc. is clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:scroll(0, 0)">Top</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you had an anchor link at the top of the page, you could do it with anchors too.

```
<a name="top"></a>
<a href='#top">top</a>
```

It'll work in browser's with Javascript disabled, but changes the url. :( It also lets you jump to anywhere the name anchor is set.

Answer (score 0):

actually, this works by itself, no need to define it.

```
<a href="#top">top</a>
```

This is a "magic" hashname value that does not need to be defined in browsers.

Just like this will "reload" the page.

```
<a href="/">reload</a>
```